# Using Pushme.to to send Push notification to iphone

Tags: php, iphone, curl, push-notification

I'm using http://www.barattalo.it/2010/08/09/send-push-notification-to-iphone-with-php-and-pushme-to/

When i call the function i get the error messages.

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in <PATH>ServiceDesk.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in <PATH>ServiceDesk.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in <PATH>ServiceDesk.php on line 17
```

Here is the code

```
function pushMeTo($widgeturl,$text,$signature) {
    $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.12) Gecko/2009070611 Firefox/3.0.12";
    if (!function_exists("curl_init")) die("pushMeTo needs CURL module, please install CURL on your php.");
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $widgeturl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    $page = curl_exec($ch);
    preg_match("/form action=\"(.*?)\"/", $page, $form_action);
    preg_match("/textarea name=\"(.*?)\"/", $page, $message_field);
    preg_match("/input type=\"text\" name=\"(.*?)\"/", $page, $signature_field);
    $ch = curl_init();
    $strpost = $message_field[1].'=' . urlencode($text) . '&'.$signature_field[1].'=' . urlencode($signature);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $strpost );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $form_action[1]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    $page = curl_exec($ch);
}


$url = "<MY URL HERE>";
 pushmeTo ($url,"This Is A Test","ServiceDesk");
```

I have never used CURL before but I'm ok with PHP.

I suspect it may be a proxy issue but I'm only allowed to set a proxy on a per script basis. Can anyone show me how to set the proxy in with CURL in this script.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$form_action[1]` is undefined ( meaning at index 1 in you're $form_action array there is nothing ) , so i would go and look at `$page` after the first curl_exec, and allso at the regex here `preg_match("/form action=\"(.*?)\"/", $page, $form_action);`

---

Edit

On a second look it looks like all youre regex are failing so again have a look at `$page` and  allso make shure all the values returned by the regex are what you need .